# vb script: Trying to open a command prompt, navigate to a directory and run a command

Tags: vbscript, dos

I need to write a script that looks in a directory, finds the latest .zip file (there are .zip and .log in there) then opens a command prompt in a different directory and runs the following command:

```
loaddb.bat -Dlc.file="C:\Program Files\XyEnterprise\SDL LiveContent\data_old\export\<name of the newest file.zip>" -Dlc.pswd=<oor password> RESTORE
```

We can not install any languages so it has to be able to run on a Windows 2003 & 2008 server so I chose vbscript...

I have everything working apart from the running the command and can't seem to crack it.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim fileNewest
Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Program Files\XyEnterprise\SDL LiveContent\data\export")

For Each aFile In oFolder.Files
sExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(aFile.Name)
    If sExtension = "log" Then
            'Msgbox "The file extension is a " & sExtension
        Else
            'Msgbox "The file extension is a " & sExtension
                         If fileNewest = "" Then
                        Set fileNewest = aFile  
                     Else
                     If fileNewest.DateCreated < aFile.DateCreated Then
                            Set fileNewest = aFile
                     End If
                    End If
                End If
Next
Msgbox "The Newest File in the folder is " & fileNewest.Name & chr(13) & "Size: " & fileNewest.Size & " bytes" & chr(13) & "Was last modified on " & FileNewest.DateLastModified 

Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%comspec% /k c: & cd ../../../Program Files\XyEnterprise\SDL LiveContent\data\export"
```

How can I now run a command after opening that Dos prompt?

Thanks,

EDIT:

Adding the answer worked with a lot of help from Alex K:

```
objShell.Run "%comspec% /k c: & cd ""C:\Program Files (x86)\XyEnterprise\SDL LiveContent\"" & """"loaddb RESTORE -Dlc.file=C:\PROGRA~2\XYENTE~1\SDLLIV~1\data\Import\" & fileNewest.Name & " -Dlc.pswd=N2kAs72z"""""
```

Comment: What facts speak for to using a commmand prompt for executing a programm?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I need to run a loaddb.bat command with a path to a file that changes every 12 hours (picked up from the script)

Comment: I see. http://ss64.com/vb/run.html contains an example. Look for the word 'DIR'. Hopefully it is what you look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote that path as it contains spaces;

```
objShell.Run "%comspec% /k c: & cd ""../../../Program Files\XyEnterprise\SDL LiveContent\data\export"""
```

Comment: I made a xxx.bat under "C:\Program Files\BBC iPlayer Desktop\" and this works for me: `objShell.Run "%comspec% /k c: & cd ""C:\Program Files\BBC iPlayer Desktop\"" & ""xxx.bat"""`

Comment: Brilliant, I have that running a test.bat file as well so thank you. How do I now pass the name of the .zip file into this string?

Comment: how about `"%comspec% /k c: & cd ""PATHHERE"" " & """" & fileNewest.Name & """"`

Comment: Got it: objShell.Run "%comspec% /k c: & cd ""C:\Program Files (x86)\XyEnterprise\SDL LiveContent\"" & """"loaddb RESTORE -Dlc.file=C:\PROGRA~2\XYENTE~1\SDLLIV~1\data\Import\" & fileNewest.Name & " -Dlc.pswd=N2kAs72z"""""

Comment: I tried quoting the path in -Dlc.file with a " but that didn't work no matter how many I put on either side so I decided to just use the shortened DOS names and it worked.